# Is there a simple way to substitute ID references for a column value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

This sounds simple, and probably is...

Alright, so I have two tables, `users` and `messages`. 
Formatted like so:

```
users
ID | username
1  | im_a_user
2  | another_user

messages
ID | FROM | TO | CONTENT
1  | 1    | 2  | Blah blah blah...
2  | 2    | 1  | Hello, World!
3  | 2    | 1  | Another message.
```

If you didn't guess, columns `FROM` and `TO` are references to the `ID` from the table `users`.

Anyhow, I'd like to make a query that returns something like this:

```
ID | FROM         | TO           | CONTENT
1  | im_a_user    | another_user | Blah blah blah...
2  | another_user | im_a_user    | Hello, World!
3  | another_user | im_a_user    | Another message.
```

I've done this before with `JOINS`, but I'm a bit rusty, and I was wondering if there was a simpler way.. If not, a query using a `JOIN` is fine.

Comment: Your original idea is better, as it practices normalization correctly. What you trying to do now is to de-normalize it. Well ... have fun!

Comment: I never stated my intentions. I'm pulling the results for viewing.

Comment: yoshi san ,do  join will be able to pull the user name into the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JOIN`s exist exactly for things like that. You need a query like this:

```
SELECT
    m.id,
    sender.username AS sender,
    recipent.username AS recipient,
    m.content
FROM messages m
    INNER JOIN users sender
    ON sender.id = `m.from`
    INNER JOIN users recipent
    ON recipient.id = m.to
```

If you have `NULL`s on columns `TO` or `FROM`, change the apropriate `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

As a side note, I'd recommend you refrain from using SQL reserved words such as `FROM` as column names.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the advice, I don't actually use `FROM`, just a quick example.

Answer (score 0):

I guess a few joins would be the best way to do this.

From the top of my head.. something like this?

```
SELECT messages.ID, from_user.username, to_user.username, messages.CONTENT FROM messages
LEFT JOIN users as from_user ON (messages.FROM = users.ID)
LEFT JOIN users as to_user ON (messages.TO = users.ID)
```

Comment: all those useless backticks gives me a headache.

Comment: Sorry about that, im just used to the backticks. I agree they are useless here :)